# How to plot Stacked histogram using gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

How can plot this data using stached histogram in gnuplot, on the xaxis am geting numbers instend of the labels in column 1. I expected the labels like "1507ml", "crusher area" ... on the xaxis. the error keep appearing in my plot command.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Which data? What have you tried? Please show your script and your result. Check [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)